# how to check whether the location list for the current window is open

Tags: quickfix, location-list

Using `getwininfo` it is possible to determine whether an window is a quickfix window or location list window.

But once a location list window is found, how can I know which window it is associated with?

Is there a more straightforward way to know whether the current window has a location list window opened

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to check whether the location list for the current window is open

You could try to inspect the `'winid'` property of the location list. If the location window is open, the value of the property should be different than zero:

```
if get(getloclist(0, {'winid':0}), 'winid', 0)
    " the location window is open
    ...
else
    " the location window is closed
    ...
endif
```

---

> once a location list window is found, how can I know which window it is associated with?

You could try to inspect the `'filewinid'` property of the location list:

```
echo get(getloclist(0, {'filewinid':0}), 'filewinid', 0)
```

This requires the Vim patch [8.1.0345](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0345).

If your Vim version doesn't include this patch, or if you use Neovim which [doesn't implement](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/3348eea429d67fdb3942a9e60d60deb8f59b3ec8/runtime/doc/eval.txt#L4260-L4271) [this property](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/3348eea429d67fdb3942a9e60d60deb8f59b3ec8/runtime/doc/eval.txt#L4349-L4373) at the moment, you could try this code instead:

```
fu! Get_associated_window() abort
    let win_ids = get(gettabinfo(tabpagenr())[0], 'windows', {})
    let loc_id = win_getid()
    return get(filter(win_ids, {i,v -> get(getloclist(v, {'winid': 0}), 'winid', 0) ==# loc_id && v !=# loc_id }) , 0, 0)
endfu
echo Get_associated_window()
```

For more information, see:

```
:h getloclist()
:h getqflist()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that quickfix/loclist windows are not really associated with any other windows/buffers, and that what you ask is not really possible out of the box.

However, if we assume that a quickfix/loclist window is associated with the window that was active when opening, then you could use something like this:

```
augroup qfidentifier
  autocmd!
  autocmd QuickFixCmdPre [c]* let g:quicklist_buffer = bufnr('.')
  autocmd QuickFixCmdPre [l]* let g:loclist_buffer = bufnr('.')
augroup END
```

This should set the `g:quicklist_buffer` and `g:loclist_buffer` variables to the buffer number that was active when the relevant quickfix or loclist command was executed. I think that should provide the relevant information that you want.

*Note: I did not test this, so it might need some adjustments.*

Comment: If I am correct, location list is associated with a window (each window can have a location list, as termed "window-local quickfix list" in `:h location-list`)

Comment: Yes, you might be right. And so the answer might not be very good, sorry. Let's hope someone else knows, then. :)